# Map Java class to MongoDb Collection in Spring Boot

Tags: database, mongodb, spring-boot, entity

How can we map the Java class in spring boot to MongoDB collection?

Is there any annotation like @Entity in spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb?

Comment: Got it. It's @Document.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [@BsonProperty](https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonProperty) for a Pojo Clas. This will automatically map the mongo document to your class..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this annotation to map a class to Mongo

```
@Document(collection = "NAME_COLLECTION_IN_MONGO")
```